# DVB Stream analysis program for Ubuntu?

Tags: video-streaming, dvb

I have DekTec DTU-238 Stream analysis probe for analysis of DVB streams (NAT, PAT, EIT, CAT tables analysis). (https://www.dektec.com/products/USB/DTU-238/) Since recently I've used provided by manufacturer stream analysis programs that run under Windows.
Ubuntu drivers I installed and the this device works fine. I couldn't find proper Ubuntu program for using this type of devices. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would not think that anyone will "reverse" engineer a software for a proprietary (non mainstream) hardware, since the code will not be open source. So I guess you'll be out of luck with Linux (you might ask the manufacturer) ...

Comment: Well, they released drivers for Linux and Windows/Linux SDK ages ago... I guess somebody made it but just don't know who :)